# Error while extracting response for type [class java.lang.Object] and content type [text/html;charset=utf-8]

Tags: resttemplate

while calling rest template getting below exception ,can anyone tell how to parse html content ?

org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [class java.lang.Object] and content type [text/html;charset=utf-8]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it Worked, 
List> messageConverters = new ArrayList>();
ResourceHttpMessageConverter converter = new ResourceHttpMessageConverter();

messageConverters.add(converter);
                        restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);